# Range is not correct in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I'm trying to make a macro to copy data from excel to another excel (which is template - `.xltx`).

So i wrote a code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerujD5()

Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim copylastrow As Long
Dim pasterow As Long

path = "C:\pc2\export\export.xls"

Set wsCopy = Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets("export")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

copylastrow  = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
pasterow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

wsCopy.Range("A2:M" & copylastrow).Copy
wsDest.Range("A5" & pasterow).PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub
```

My problems:

**It is copying the data, but not into correct cell. Template has 4 rows, so i have to copy them into the 5. row. But it copies into the 55. row.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the first free row from the destination sheet and write it to the variable `pasterow`. Assuming that your destination sheet has four lines filled, this will be 5.

Later you write `wsDest.Range("A5" & pasterow).PasteSpecial xlValues`. Now VBA will concatenate the string `"A5"` and the content of your variable `pasterow`, that is the same as `"A5" & 5"`, and that will result in `"A55"`.

If you know for sure that you will have always four lines filled, you can get rid of the variable `pasterow` and simply write

```
wsDest.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

But the better attempt is to use it and write

```
wsDest.Range("A" & pasterow).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

As an alternative, you can also write

```
wsDest.Cells(pasterow, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

or

```
wsDest.Cells(pasterow, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
```